# On Windows 7 SWT 4.3 setSelection doesn't move the caret at end of text

Tags: java, swt

I have the following Text in swt. I'm trying to display in a text widget a specific text and move the caret to the end just in case the user wants to add something.

The problem is that the caret is always **before** last character and not **after**

```
    text = new Text(group, SWT.BORDER);
    text.addListener(SWT.KeyDown, e -> {
        if (e.keyCode == SWT.ARROW_UP) {
            String prevText = "some text from history";
            text.setText(prevText);
            text.setSelection(prevText.length());
            //This doesn't work either: caret is stil before last character
            //text.setSelection(prevText.length()+10);
        }
    });
```

More details:

```
Windows7
swt-4.3
SWT-OS: win32
SWT-WS: win32
SWT-Arch: x86_64
```

On an OSX it behaves properly.

Comment: Why do you use a `Listener` for `SWT.KeyDown`? When exactly do you want to move the cursor to the end?

Comment: The code attempts to navigate through history of commands. I kept it to show that setting text is made in a listener (I thought that this might be influenced by threads). After I'm pressing key up I expect a new text to appear in the Text and the cursor in that text to be at the end of the text.

Comment: Can you try another listener type or a key event that doesn't change the caret position? `SWT.ARROW_UP` will actually move the caret to the left, which will result in it being before the last character.

Comment: oooo. I see what you did here ... I'll try it and let you know. thanks.

Comment: Great, let me know if this solves your problem, then I can post this as a proper answer.

Comment: I checked. I added a `if(e.character=='a')` and it always adds an a to the text. I didn't noticed the behaviour on OsX since ArrowUp always goes at the beginning of line and ArrowDown to the end of line. On windows it goes one character towards the beginning of line or one to the end.

Comment: So does that mean your problem is resolved?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124335/discussion-between-raisercostin-and-baz).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can confirm your observation running the snippet with SWT 3.106 (as shipped with Eclipse 4.6) on Windows 7.

It is the <kbd>Up</kbd> key that changes the position of the caret to the before-last character. On Windows, the <kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Down</kbd> keys change the cursor position to the left and right respectively. To prevent that from happening you need to stop the Text widget from consuming the key event with

```
event.doit = false;
```

This issue only applies to single-line text input fields. If a Text is created with `new Text( parent, SWT.MULTI )`, setting the selection works as expected.

Alternatively, for single-line text input fields, use the overloaded `setSelection(in,int)` or `setSelection(Point)` method. For example:

```java
int selection = text1.getText().length() + 1;
text1.setSelection( selection, selection );
```

Answer (score 2):

On Windows, using the <kbd>▲</kbd> and <kbd>▼</kbd> arrow keys will move the caret left or right.

This only applies to single line `Text` widgets though.

So this is very much the intended behaviour and not a bug.